# Is it still possible to debug opentap 1.5.0 in eclipse/netbeans?

Tags: crm, erp, opentaps

I followed [this tutorial](http://www.opensourcestrategies.com/ofbiz/ofbiz_eclipse.php) to the letter but all I get are errors after errors what's more, because it's so old there's somewhat of an extra step missing as eclipse asks what type of Java application it is when I try to run it despite the errors. Any help or pointers as to how it's possible to achieve this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that you could import eclipse project into netbeans as it already contained an eclipse project.